# How do I make InkWell uncompressible? flutter

Tags: flutter

I have InkWell, how do I make it non-compressible? Where I have a container that I will be able to press on it in a specific case only, otherwise I want to cancel the pressure

```
InkWell(
onTap: () {
if (my[index]["status"] == "ok") {
  myshowModalBottomSheet(context);
 } else {}
 },
 child: Container()
```

This is the case, but in the other case, the container can be pressurized, but without anything happening, I want to cancel the pressure

I don't want the interaction to happen from the container in the second condition

Comment: Please remove the image and add the code as text, following this post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Just so you know, compressible and pressurized are not used in English in this context. You probably mean pressable or clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InkWell will be disabled if all of its fields are null. So, you can give the onTap a function only when it's necessary.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: my[index]["status"] == "ok" ? 
   () {
     ...
    } : null,
 child: Container(),
)
```